# Does GlassFish Web Profile supports Web Services?

Tags: web-services, jaxb, glassfish, jax-ws

We prefer the light version of Glassfish (Web Profile), but also need web services support.

They say [here](http://glassfish.java.net/webprofileORfullplatform31x.html) that only the Full version has JAX-WS 2.2 and JAXB 2.2 which are, AFAIN, the fundamentals of web services.

However, I know that these two are also shipped with JDK6, so my question is, does GlassFish in Web Profile mode, deployed on JDK 6, will support web services as well? and if it's only a matter of different versions of JAX-WS & JAXB , will it pose any problem?

Comment: May be it is simple to run glassfish Web profile and deploy web service hello world application to see wil ti works or not? :)